# Key encyption, front-end back-end question

Tags: django, database, encryption, secret-key

I have a front end which has some api credentials which are needed to receive information for the front-end. I also want to store these credentials in a database so that the user does not need to enter these api credentials with every log in, rather the api credentials are 'there'. How should these api keys be stored in the back end and then de-crypted in the front-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should these api keys be stored in the back end and then de-crypted in the front-end?

If the credentials are to be stored in a database as encrypted, maybe you could use the database-native feature to encrypt the data as the simplest option.  That depends on the database used.

Transport between backend and frontend should be encrypted using the https.